# Special case of Hibernate LazyInitializationException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, lazy-loading

today at work I encountered a **strange** `LazyInitializationException` when running a spring boot **integration test**. The most common errors have to be excluded:

- Transaction is open when executing the incriminated code. Indeed `@Transactional` is used and **logs confirm that**.
- The transaction method is called by another class and not by the same class, so letting Spring AOP do the "magic" by opening and closing transaction without code anything.
- During the all execution the code is run in the same thread (`@Transactional` is thread-bound)

This is the code (names of things modified) where the exception happens:

```
@UtilityClass
public class UpdateStrategy {

    public <A extends ObjectWithLazyCollections> Result<Nothing> updateOrAddLazyCollection(A objectWithLazyCollections,
                                                            Collection<Field> fields,
                                                            BiFunction<A, Field, Result<Nothing>> addOperation,
                                                            BiFunction<A, Field, Result<Nothing>> updateOperation) {
        return objectWithLazyCollections.getFields().stream() // this is not a lazy collection
            .map(field -> {
                System.out.println(objectWithLazyCollections.getLazyCollection()); // // This will avoid the LazyInitializationException
                if (existingFields.contains(field)) {
                    System.out.println(objectWithLazyCollections.getLazyCollection()); // This will throw a LazyInitializationException
                    return updateOperation.apply(objectWithLazyCollections, field); // Without any prints, during the execution of this method, the exception is thrown.
                }
                return addOperation.apply(objectWithLazyCollections, field); 
            })
            .reduce(Result.success(), Result::merge);
    }

}
```

I've added two lines where a print the lazy collection, to force the inizialization of the collection, to understand where the exception can be thrown. **If a run my test with the first print it will work**. However **if I delete the first print** statement the `LazyInitializationException` is thrown at the next print statement.

Basically if the lazy collection is initialized just before the if test is passing. If I try to access the lazy collection just after the if, a LIE is thrown.

Why this happens?

**UPDATE**:

This in printed in the console after enabling the `org.hibernate.internal: TRACE` (app logs are hidden):

```
...
2023-07-17 11:46:10,663 TRACE [main] org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.<init>:287 - Opened Session [032a4aab-0c4f-444d-a957-005830fde4ec] at timestamp: 1689594370663
2023-07-17 11:46:10,666 TRACE [main] org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion:2424 - SessionImpl#beforeTransactionCompletion()
2023-07-17 11:46:10,666 TRACE [main] org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush:488 - Automatically flushing session
2023-07-17 11:46:10,670 TRACE [main] org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.afterTransactionCompletion:2439 - SessionImpl#afterTransactionCompletion(successful=true, delayed=false)
2023-07-17 11:46:10,670 TRACE [main] org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.closeWithoutOpenChecks:403 - Closing session [032a4aab-0c4f-444d-a957-005830fde4ec]
2023-07-17 11:46:10,671 TRACE [main] org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl$SessionBuilderImpl.openSession:1333 - Opening Hibernate Session.  tenant=null
2023-07-17 11:46:10,671 TRACE [main] org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.<init>:287 - Opened Session [9ac71002-40e2-48c8-94d3-6466eb8a45e2] at timestamp: 1689594370671
2023-07-17 11:46:10,695 INFO  [main] ...
2023-07-17 11:46:10,935 INFO  [main] ...
2023-07-17 11:46:11,111 INFO  [boundedElastic-11] ...
2023-07-17 11:46:11,232 TRACE [boundedElastic-11] org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl$SessionBuilderImpl.openSession:1333 - Opening Hibernate Session.  tenant=null
2023-07-17 11:46:11,236 TRACE [boundedElastic-11] org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.<init>:287 - Opened Session [0fedd4ba-2580-459d-acfa-2880e410e28d] at timestamp: 1689594371234
2023-07-17 11:46:11,263 TRACE [boundedElastic-11] org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion:2424 - SessionImpl#beforeTransactionCompletion()
2023-07-17 11:46:11,264 TRACE [boundedElastic-11] org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush:488 - Automatically flushing session
2023-07-17 11:46:11,277 TRACE [boundedElastic-11] org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.afterTransactionCompletion:2439 - SessionImpl#afterTransactionCompletion(successful=true, delayed=false)
2023-07-17 11:46:11,277 TRACE [boundedElastic-11] org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.closeWithoutOpenChecks:403 - Closing session [0fedd4ba-2580-459d-acfa-2880e410e28d]
2023-07-17 11:46:11,285 WARN  [main] ...
2023-07-17 11:46:11,473 INFO  [main] ...
2023-07-17 11:46:11,588 INFO  [main] ...
2023-07-17 11:46:11,613 INFO  [main] ...
2023-07-17 11:46:12,197 INFO  [main] ...
2023-07-17 11:46:12,201 INFO  [main] ...
true -- this is the entityManager.isOpen() output, right before the code that is generating the exception
2023-07-17 11:46:12,320 ERROR [main] ...
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: XXX, could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:614)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:218)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:591)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:149)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.iterator(PersistentBag.java:387)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.estimateSize(Spliterators.java:1865)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterator.getExactSizeIfKnown(Spliterator.java:414)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:508)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:596)
    at .... updateOperation(...)
```

I tried also to print the session contained in the lazy collection:

```
abstractPersistentCollection.getSession()
```

What I noticed is that starting from the second iteration in the stream it becomes null, but the is no sign in the logs that the connection has been closed.

Comment: LazyInitializationException indicates an attempt to access unfetched data outside the context of an open stateful Session. (from https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/LazyInitializationException.html ) After the first call of `getLazyCollection()`, are you sure about the session is still opened when you call that method again?

Comment: I know what the exception means and I enabled hibernate logs to make sure the session is open and it is. it ss very odd that if the attempt to access unfetched data is done after the if, it fails.

Comment: Simplify the code. Remove the stream. Remove the calls to `updateOperation` and `addOperation`.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the reason why you get `LIE` on the second call is that in your Spring Boot  you have [Open-Session-in-View](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-open-session-in-view) enabled (default behavior). Please check the application log for

```
spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database  queries may be performed during view rendering.Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
```

If there's this warning then add this to your `application.properties`:

```
spring.jpa.open-in-view=false
```

When you fetch the lazy properties for the second time there could be no connection available as the connection pool is exhausted, so try to add more connections in your config.

Another possible culprit is

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans=true
```

Setting this property to `true` should be [avoided](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-lazy-loading-workaround) as it again increases the number of session (and connections taken from the pool) causing pool exhaustion.

Comment: The open in view is indeed enabled. However, I catch this error during an IT test, without making http call. For this reason I'd also exclude the fact the the pool is exhausted, because it's a test where just one JDBC connection is needed. Moreover I think is not 100% (i'll update the thread) that I've the exception only if I do not initialize the lazy connection before the if, which is odd

Answer (score 0):

Strange behaviour at the first glance. `LazyInitializationException` mostly happens when the session that is used to load the entity is already closed when you access that entity 's lazy loaded collection at the first time.

So sounds like the related session is somehow closed after executing `existingFields.contains(field)`. Suggest to try the following for troubleshooting :

1. Revise the function such that you can access the `Session` (or `EntityManager` if using JPA) and call its method `isOpen()` to verify if the session is really closed :

```java
   if (existingFields.contains(field)) {
       session.isOpen() // verify if the session is still open             
    }
```

2. Change the logger level of `org.hibernate.internal` to TRACE. When the session is closed , it will log `Closing session [xxxxxx]` at `SessionImpl#closeWithoutOpenChecks()`. If it really exist in the log , place the breakpoint at there to see who close it.

Comment: session.isOpen() returns always true, even right before the exception. The org.hibernate.internal set TRACE show me that a session is closed but as there are multiple sessions involved I don't think it's helping.

Comment: so TRACE at least show you the session may be  closed. so don't think it is not helpful. And don't understand why it will involve multiple sessions as just like you said all code execute in the same thread. And you only need one session to execute codes for one thread

Comment: After the log Closing session [xxxxxx] entity manager still says that the session is open anyway.

Comment: are you sure the session that you checked on is really the session that is used to load the entity ?

Comment: Sorry, the Closing session [xxxxxx] log I saw it indeed regards another session which is opened an closed in another thread. In the main thread (where the code above is run) the session is not closed indeed, that's why the entity manager says it is opened.

Comment: I updated the post with some logs.

Comment: notice that the session `032a4aabxxx` is closed , are you sure that the entity is not loaded by this session ?

Comment: given an `entityManager` instance , you can call   `entityManager.unwrap(SessionImpl.class).getSessionIdentifier()` to print out its its session ID for verification.